# fresh CentOS image in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos

There are a lot of CentOS images in AWS for creating EC2 instance. 
In most of them various application and services are pre-installed,for example:

I found most of them having apache, bind, postfix & even mysql is installed, 
but, I want a fresh image, where I'll install the services whatever I need, 
***so which CentOS image is a fresh image***, could anybody tell me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this [Official Centos Image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00O7WM7QW?qid=1510588240139&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title) from AWS Market Place.

Thanks

Comment: found no image named/titles 'Official CentOS Image' 
could you please tell me how it is titled/named?

Comment: That is a URL click on it and it will redirect to page.